# Capturing every repetition of group

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check whether a string matches the following logical pattern:

string, string, string

I NEED TO USE A REGEXP and I cannot use functions.

For example the following string should match:

```
hello,hola, ciao,bye -> [hello,hola,ciao,bye]
```

The following shouldn't match:

```
hello -> []
```

I'm using this regexp right now but it's working fine only for the first string.
I'm trying to exclude the single string without a comma in the second example.

```
([^,]+)
```

The following regexp doesn't work neither: isn't it supposed to match every group and then the end of the line BUT before the end of the line a comma followed by a string must be present?

```
([^,]+)(?<=,)$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: No functions allowed, the language shouldn't matter! However javascript :)

Comment: @DamianoBarbati: Well the capturing facility is not something *inherent* to regexes. It's just because many programming languages have made large regex libraries aspects like capturing are well supported. But the framework thus matters.

Comment: It's false, the language matter because languages haven't always the same regex engine.

Comment: nope, updated question. I actually need a true/false match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+)+$
```

Comment: yes! It works! May I ask you to explain a little? ^[^,]+ is to match the first string, then a non capturing group which matches a comma and again a string without comma repeated until the end of the line. right?

Comment: @DamianoBarbati: yes, the description is good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match on `([^,]+),?`, and iterate over each match. Regex doesn't have the concept of "arrays".

Alternatively, you can "split" on `,` and be done.

Comment: Edit: I don't quite need the array, but just matching correctly a sequence of "string,string,string" and not a simple "string"

Comment: @DamianoBarbati What about `if (str.indexOf(',') > -1) {`??

Comment: I see, do you need it to be "space" free? You might not be able to have a one-liner to do that. You could first see if it "has a comma", and then just strip spaces.

Comment: what do you mean with space free?

Comment: I mean turning `hola, ciao` into `hola,ciao` (without whitespace)

Comment: nope that's not needed, I don't need the groups but just correct matching even if groups are not trimmed.

Comment: I updated the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this with a positive look ahead :

```
/\w+(?=,)/g
```

Example with perl:

```
$ echo 'hello,hola, ciao,bye' | 
    perl -lne 'my @a = /\w+(?=,)/g; print join "\n", @a'
hello
hola
ciao
```

Or using `split` :

```
$ echo 'hello,hola, ciao,bye' |
    perl -lne 'my @a = split /[,\s]+/g; print join "\n", @a'
hello
hola
ciao
bye
```

Comment: nice one, i'm on that path too but that doesn't match last repetition

Comment: I don't understand: which one is supposed to be the correct regexp? Thanks anyway!